# How can I combine these two functions?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImageSwiftUI to display images but need to supply an image of type binding for my ImageView structs within a ForEach loop.

How do I do this using SDWebImage?

Thank you!

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var duplicateVM : DuplicateUserVM

   var body: some View {
      List { 
          ForEach(duplicateVM.users, id: \.id) { user in
             ImageView(idImage: WebImage(url: URL(string: user.idUrl)))
             //                           ^ How do I supply the URL??
        }
     }   
   }
} 

struct ImageView: View {
    @Binding var idImage: UIImage?  
    
    var body: some View {
       Image(uiImage: idImage).resizable()       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass only the name and add all the code inside the ImageView.

```
struct ContentView98: View {
   @ObservedObject var duplicateVM : DuplicateUserVM

   var body: some View {
      List {
        ForEach(duplicateVM.users, id: \.id) { user in
             ImageView(idImage: user)
        }
     }
   }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    @Binding var idImage: String
    
    var body: some View {
        WebImage(url: URL(string: idImage)).resizable()
    }
}
```

---

Or create string init for the `WebImage`

```
extension WebImage {
    init(string: String) {
        self.init(url: URL(string: string))
    }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    @Binding var idImage: String
    var body: some View {
        WebImage(string: idImage).resizable()
    }
}
```